# Pip extras dependency substitution

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm creating a module that has only 1 pypi dependency. This dependency has 2 packages on pypi. One that makes use of a system library and the other packages a binary distribution of that library. They look like:

```
theirmodule
theirmodule-binary
```

My module depends on `theirmodule` but I want users of my module to be able to decide if they want the lib version of the dependency or the binary version. I see in the [docs about Extras](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). I could do:

```
setup(
    name="MyModule",
    ...
    extras_require={
        "BIN":  ["theirmodule-binary>=1.2"]
    }
)
```

But then if the user does `pip install mymodule[BIN]` pip will install both `theirmodule` and `theirmodule-binary`. That would be a conflict since both have the same underlying import string eg:

```
import theirmodule
```

is used for both. How can this be handled without providing 2 separate pypi packages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

`setup.py`

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='My-Project',
    # ...
    extras_require={
        'Extra_Dependency_As_Binary': ['Dependency-Project-Binary>=1.2'],
        'Extra_Dependency_As_Library': ['Dependency-Project-Library<=3.4'],
    },
)
```

And then instruct the users of *My-Project* (maybe in the *README* file) to install by specifying either one of the *extra* explicitly. For example with *pip* it could be one or the other of:

- `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install 'My-Project[Extra_Dependency_As_Binary]'`
- `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install 'My-Project[Extra_Dependency_As_Library]'`